# How to use JOIN for my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

One contains:

```
id, album name, description, etc...
```

Another contains:

```
id, album id, photo
```

I want to get album details and its photos through `album id`?

How can I achieve this?

Can I use left join?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your tables are called `Albums` and `Photos`:

```
SELECT Albums.*, Photos.Photo
FROM Albums
LEFT JOIN Photos
ON Albums.id=Photos.album_id
WHERE Albums.id=42
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, a.album_name ..., b.photo 
from albums a 
left join OtherTable b on a.id = b.album_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM album a JOIN photo p
ON a.id=p.album_id 
WHERE a.id= 11
```